# Execute code in console application every minute

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a simple application in C# which takes PDF from one location and moves it to another location.

```
namespace MoveFiles
{
class Program
{
    public static string destinationPath = @"S:\Re\C";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //location of PDF files

        string path = @"S:\Can\Save";

        //get ONLY PDFs

        string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.pdf");


        foreach (string file in filePath)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            string dest = destinationPath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(file);
            File.Move(file, dest);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}
```

}

If I run this app it does the work, however, I need this code to be executed every minute. I could of used `task scheduler` to run the app every minute, but unfortunately the minimum runtime is 5 min.

I have tried to use `while(true)` but it doesn't work. If I add more PDF files to the folder while the app is running it will not move it to different folder.

I found a suggestion online to use `Timer` but I'm having issues:

```
static void Main(string[] args)   
{
    Timer t = new Timer(60000); // 1 sec = 1000, 60 sec = 60000
    t.AutoReset = true;
    t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(t_Elapsed);
    t.Start();
  }
  private static void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
     // do stuff every minute
   }
```

But I get compiler errors:

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Threading.TimerCallback'   C:\Win\MoveFiles\MoveFiles\MoveFiles\Program.cs 22  33  MoveFiles

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: There are two Timer classes, System.Threading.Timer and System.Timers.Timer. You've got code for System.Timers.Timer but Timer is resolving to System.Threading.Timer. I'm guessing there is a using for System.Threading that you haven't shown us.

Comment: @mikez, that's the entire app, there's no more code in this app...

Comment: There are using directives somewhere (e.g. `using System;`). Otherwise, those references to Console, Path, Directory, etc. classes wouldn't compile.

Comment: i hope we can change the Task Scheduler "Repear Task Min" to "1 Min"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was easier than I thought.

Here's how I solved it. It may not be the best possible solution, but it works for my need.

I created a `while` loop and used `Thread.Sleep(60000)` to force the app to go to sleep before executing again.

```
namespace MoveFiles
{
class Program
{
    public static string destinationPath = @"S:\Re\C";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //location of PDF files

        while (true)
        {
            string path = @"S:\Can\Save";

            //get ONLY PDFs

            string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.pdf");


            foreach (string file in filePath)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
                string dest = destinationPath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(file);
                File.Move(file, dest);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: For my own project I was considering the same solution. I'm only not sure whether this will suck up alot of memory on the pc?

Comment: @JorisDecraecker, unfortunately, I do not remember how much memory it used up while running, since I used this code years ago, but I don't believe it used enough to hog the machine. Of course, in my case this code didn't run more than 30 minutes.

Comment: I found a better way to tackle this (atleast for my issue). I'm gonna use the Task Scheduler on a batch program. If the program failes, the scheduler will run it again after 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the constructors here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

This is one of the method signatures for this constructor:

```
Timer(TimerCallback, Object, Int32, Int32)
```

You can't instantiate a System.Threading.Timer with just the interval. Either use a System.Timers.Timer instead (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) or you have to supply the TimerCallback, Object state (can be null), due time, and period. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7(v=vs.110).aspx under "Parameters."

Answer (score -1):

```
private static Timer timer;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    timer = new Timer(timer_Elapsed);
    timer.Change(60000, 60000);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void timer_Elapsed(object o)
{
    // do stuff every minute
}
```

Comment: it never goes to `private static void t_Elapsed(object o)` The app closes...?

Comment: @user1426542 You need to keep the Console application alive somehow.  When is it supposed to close?

Comment: This app should run at least for a day. It's a temp app that moves files from one location to another. It should close when user closes the app.

Comment: @user1426542 I edited my answer so that it closes when the user presses a key.

Comment: I moved the code that moves the files in `timer_Elapsed` event. Now, in this line `timer = new Timer(t_Elapsed);` I assume that it should go to the `timer_Elapsed` execute the code... But it never goes there...